# How to force MATLAB run CNN on GPU

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I write a program to train my data (images with trainNetwork). I use a computer with the GPU **nvidia quadpro M4000** and RAM 64GB to train. I write a short code here:

```
opts=trainingOptions('sgdm','InitialLearnRate',1e-3,'MaxEpochs',200,'MiniBatchSize',64,'Plots','training-progress', 'ExecutionEnvironment', 'auto');
net=trainNetwork(trainingData,layers,opts);
```

As description on Mathworks site, the `trainNetwork` will choose the GPU when it is available. Although I tried to change `ExecutionEnvironment` to gpu, it still run on CPU only. How to force the `trainNetwork` run on GPU?

Comment: What is the output of `>> gpuDevice` ?

Comment: *Mathworld* sounds like a great holiday resort, not the authors of MATLAB though...

Comment: Sorry, Mathworks :)

Comment: How do you know its running on CPU and not on GPU?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: there is no gpu on computer or CUDA is not enabled.

Comment: @Wolfie: on the training GUI, running on Single CPU

Comment: @Freelancer can you run [nvidia-smi](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) successfully, and what is the output ?